# Django User Model with ManyToMany relationship, how to update/ create new profile with relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I have a class that has a one to one relationship with my User class. In this class (called UserLocations), I have a field that is a ManyToManyField on another class (we will call this model Locations).

In my Locations class, I have a field called 'abbreviation' which is a four character abbreviation of the location name. I have a front end website where an admin can create a new user or update an existing users locations (based on the abbreviation field).

When I am going to create a new user, how would I set/ update that ManyToMany field based on the 'abbreviation' field? It is a list of abbreviations that tie to that 'abbreviation' field in the Locations model.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Assuming you get the chosen abbreviation in a variable called location_abbreviation:    
desired_location = Location.objects.get(abbreviation=location_abbreviation)
user = User.objects.create(...)
user_location = UserLocation.objects.create(user=user, ...)
user_location.locations = [desired_location]
user_location.save()
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.